# Need for Display Adapter of Acer Aspire One D270 on Window 8, 64 Bit.

Tags: windows-8, display, display-driver

I have installed Windows 8 on Acer Aspire One D270 and I cannot change its display settings because of driver.please help me in finding one for this machine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the latest driver for a Intel GMA 3600 which is used in your Acer:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22633

But it looks like there is **only a 32Bit driver**, so you need to install the 32Bit Version of Windows 8 and not 64Bit.

Comment: Today I used external LCD with my netbook. The display changed to 1024x768 as the display was changed to UB4A. All apps of windows 8 were working very well. It remained working till I removed the cable and restarted it. It again became Mobile PC Display. Please is it possible to engage this driver option  permanently. Thanks

Comment: install the 32Bit Windows and be happy. The Acer is so slow, you don't need 64Bit.